# Windows 11 not detected by GRUB

Tags: multi-boot, efi

Recently I installed Debian 12 and can't boot into Windows 11 anymore.
I noticed there is no EFI system partition (ESP) present on my Windows disk.

**EDIT:**
*CREATING NEW EFI SYSTEM PARTITION FOR WINDOWS 11*

Booting from the Windows installation disk to open Command Prompt (Shift+F10).

I had to shrink my Windows partition using diskpart (shrink command) to create an EFI partition.

I used the following commands for creating an EFI partition in diskpart:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk #
list partition
select partition #
shrink desired=100
create partition efi size=100
format quick fs=fat32
assign letter=s
list partition
list volume
exit
```

Copied the boot files to EFI partition with BCDBoot (X=volume letter of Windows OS partition:

```
bcdboot X:\windows /s S:
```

Reboot into Debian and update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Windows 11 is finally recognized by GRUB and added to the menu entries.
However when I try to boot Windows, my system just restarts.
How can I fix this?

Comment: I normally get Windows to create its own UEFI partition.

Comment: I will try with Windows installation disc, thanks!

Comment: *Caveat:* Windows sometimes does not play nicely with Linux. It may create the partition, but *might* disable grub. When starting with a new disk, I find it best to let Windows make the first partitions and install itself, then create some free space and install Linux.

Comment: Can I assume this is supposed to be a dual-boot system? Can you explain how you built this system, the steps you took?

Comment: Yes this is a dual-boot system. I've installed Debian on a secondary SSD next to Windows on my internal SSD.

Comment: That is not what I asked. I asked you to explain HOW you built the dual boot system. We need to know how the system was broken to give you the best answer regarding how to fix it.

Comment: ... and if Windows 11 was working before - it support UEFI mode ONLY! - then the ESP was there, no doubt whatsoever. but probably in another drive. FYI, the ESP and the main system(s) partition(s) can be anywhere as long as the firmware is set correctly to boot from said ESP. Your report here suggests one or several mistakes happened, reason why @music2myear is insisting on the "How" rather than the "where" you're insisting on but totally irrelevant.